# Ratio test - $\sum_{k \geq 0} a_k z^k$ - Radius of convergence

Tags: complex-analysis

Let the serie $f(z)=\sum_{k \geq 0} a_k z^k$ with radius of convergence $R>0$ on the disque $D(0;R)$. Show that if the serie $\sum_{k \geq 0} f^{(k)}(0)$ is convergent, then $R= \infty$.

I think I have to use the property $a_k= \frac{1}{k!}f^{(k)}(0)$ and the ratio test. How could I complete this proof with the ratio test? Is anyone could do that?

We suppose implicitely in the question $|\frac{a_k}{a_{k+1}}| \to L<1$ so $|(k+1)|\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{f^{(k+1)}(0)}| \to L < 1$, but how could I use this  information to find the radius of convergence? Is L is suppose to be my radius of convergence?

Comment: Why do you suppose $\bigl\lvert \frac{a_k}{a_{k+1}}\bigr\rvert$ is convergent? That's a completely unnecessary assumption. Why are you so fixated on the ratio test?

Comment: Because I want to understand well the ratio test.

Comment: @DanielFischer Is it possible for you to give me a comprehensive explanation of the issue that I can understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\sum f^{(k)} (0) $ is convergent the sequence $b_k =|f^{(k)} (0)| $ is bounded by some real number $M>0.$ Therefore $$\frac{1}{R} =\limsup_n \sqrt[n]{|a_n |} =\limsup_n \sqrt[n]{\frac{|b_n |}{n!}}\leq \limsup_n\sqrt[n]{\frac{M}{n!}} =0$$

Comment: I know how to do that with this definition, but I would like with the ratio test. Could you able to do that?